# Which of the main characters in the Mahabharata lie for definite, other than Kunti?

Tags: mahabharata

Kunti lies about the women not being able to have sex with more than 3 people [because she does exactly that immediately before](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118372.html) and [she knows she did it four times](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375082.html). Does any of the other characters do something similar? Also, this was completely avoidable by getting Madri to do it. Is there any other character who does this?

> Kunti warned, **The wise do not sanction a fourth child even in case of emergency**. The woman who has intercourse with four different men is called a prostitute, and with a fifth she is called a harlot. Therefore, O great King, because you are learned in the scriptures, please do not ask me again to bear children.

> "Kunti said,
>
> 'You are Kunti’s son, and not Radha’s. Nor is Adhiratha your father. You, O Karna, art not born in the Suta order. Believe what I say. You were brought forth by me while a maiden. **I held you first in my womb. O son, you were born in the palace of Kuntiraja**. O Karna, that divine Surya who blazes forth in light and makes everything visible, O foremost of all wielders of weapons, **begat you upon me**.

Comment: How u concluded she lied...https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36761/12304 - she is referring to having sons with **Niyoga** (having sex for niyoga).. By Niyoga she had only 3 sons Yudhishthir, Bhima and Arjuna ... Karna from Surya wasn't from Niyoga as by that time she wasn't married..

Comment: @YDS There is nothing tying her statement "intercourse with four different men" to Niyoga. Yes she only used Niyoga three times, but that doesn't really change anything.